# Can't return data from postgresql through Ajax Request in real device i.e. Android Phone

Tags: android, ajax, postgresql, cordova

I'm using cordova 6.5. Here's my Javascript

```
function my()
{
  var modulecode = document.getElementById("ModuleCode");
//ll
 $.ajax({
    url:"http://192.168.x.xxx/testconn.php",
    method:"POST",
    dataType:"json",
    cache:false,
    data:{ModuleCode:modulecode.value},
    success: function(html){

                  var DOM =jQuery("#DOM");
                   DOM.empty();
                   jQuery.each(html,function(key,value){
                   DOM.append("<li>" + value.Module_Name + "</li>")

       });

    },

    error: function(e){
        alert("Error : " + e.message);
    }
        });
    }
```

When I put error.code in the error callback it returns some scripted minified form Javascript but this return "undefined"